# why new variable is created when 'this' in most of the examples

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, this

I am reading AngularJS from [tutorial](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/ngfilter). I dont know the why they are declaring new variable for using 'this' keyword. Without that new keyword, We can use 'this' without new variable(self).

```
function TestCtrl() {

  var self = this;
    self.people = [
      {
        name: "Eric Simons",
        born: "Chicago"
      },
      {
        name: "Albert Pai",
        born: "Taiwan"
      },
      {
        name: "Matthew Greenster",
        born: "Virginia"
      }
    ];
}

angular.module('app', [])
.controller('TestCtrl', TestCtrl);
```

Any difference ?

Comment: Probably because `this` changes depending on how the method is called and in asynchronous methods. Caching solves `this`.

Comment: Any link or any stack overflow explanation to brief?

Comment: If we are using parent,child function we can use this self? otherwise what is the use of this new self variable.

Comment: @nisar at the provided example the variable `self` is redundant

Comment: That is my question  @MysterX. No longer we can use this self but why I can see this in many examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context of `this` changes depending on the place you use it.

```
controller('myController', function() {

   var a = this;


   $myElement.each(function(){
      var b = this;
   })
})
```

In the above example the contexts of `this` in the places they are used are different.

It might be necessary sometimes to save a reference to `this` in order to use it somewhere else.

Comment: That is only one example

Comment: I know the a,b use @Charlie H , we cant use this as for both function. that s why v r creating a,b to use this as separate. If I dont have child fun (an example in my question)..why use self?

Comment: In your case there is no particular reason to save the reference to `this`. The only possible reason could be that there are more than one ways to do things sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

In the example that you provided assigning `this` to a variable is not necessary, but is often done by convention as it can improve the readability of code.

The object that `this` refers to changes depending on the scope in which it is used. By assigning it to a variable in a particular scope you pin down that object so that you can refer to it in child scopes.

You are not using any child scopes so you could get away with just referring to `this` directly.

Comment: I am not using child scope.

Comment: Then you can get away with just using `this` as it is. The reason you might choose not to is for readability. Aside from that it doesn't really make a difference.